# WPF: XAML as Resource or Page

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, msbuild

for WPF projects it is possible to compile the *.xaml files as `Page` or as `Resource`.

`Resource` directly stores the raw *.xaml file in the resources of the assembly. That works fine for files that have no code behind and no "special" behaviour. Meaning simple `<ResourceDictionary>` files work fine, except for the one related to the theme (`Theme\Generic.xaml`).

The files set to `Page` are compiled into a BAML file and stored in the resources. This supports everything the raw *.xaml file supports and all the special cases and code-behind stuff on top.

In an test project I was unable to find any significant differences between both methods. The `Resource` method has the disadvantage that the file is not checked. Means it does not have to contain legal XAML code. How ever including it into a `Window` and using the content works if the `<ResourceDictionary>` is stored as `Resource` or as `Page` just the same.

Naturally I'd set the files to `Page` to get the error checking. I fail to see a reason why to use the `Resource` method. How ever in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/wpf-application-resource-content-and-data-files) the method with the handling the files as `Resource` is mentioned first, but without reasoning why anyone would use it for *.xaml files.

So the question is:
**Is there a reason for setting WPF XAML files to `Resource`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a reason for setting WPF XAML files to Resource?

It depends on your requirements. If you want the XAML to be compiled into BAML by the compiler, you should set the `Build Action` to `Page`.

If you want a loose uncompiled XAML file, you could set the `Build Action` to `Content`.

You could set the `Build Action` to `Resource` if you want to embed a loose XAML file into your assembly as a resource instead of copying it to the output folder as content for some reason. Whether you want to do this or whether "there is a reason" for doing this depends on your specific requirements.

But I wouldn't recommend you to change the default `Build Action` of `Page` unless you have a reason to do so.

Comment: The strange thing is that the first example in the page I linked in the question showcases the method to declare a XAML file as `Resource` and not as `Page`. That is the confusing part for me, why they would show this variant first.

Comment: Well, the documentation exemplifies how to use resource files. The XAML content is just an example. It also states that "if a XAML file is configured as a Resource item ... the raw XAML is compiled into an assembly rather than a binary version of the raw XAML." So there is no reason to be confused. As I said, don't change the default build action unless you have a reason to do so.